# ValueError: cannot insert column, already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column called `Soru-TR`. There are two Turkish data in the column. What I want to do is to translate the data in the `Soru-TR` column and then save it under the `Soru-EN` column.

The error I get in the output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    df.insert(1, "Soru-EN", output2)
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4443, in insert
    raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {column}, already exists")
ValueError: cannot insert Soru-EN, already exists
```

[before running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwk3e.png)
[after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hlYV.png)

```py
import os
from typing import List
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import translate_v2

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\translate-598740482087.json"
translate_client = translate_v2.Client()
target = "en"
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

for i in df.index:
    x = df['Soru-TR'][i]
    output = translate_client.translate(x, target_language=target)
    output2 = output['translatedText']
    df.insert(1, "Soru-EN", output2)
    with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', mode='a', engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sayfa1', index=False)
    
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', mode='a', engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sayfa1', index=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  please refer to guidelines here while submitting a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Iterating the DF in a for loop is not a best approach. Instead you can use df.apply and then call your function to translate, and the result you can populate in a new column, this eliminates the need of insert. finally you write the df to Excel

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df["Soru-EN"] = "Pending" # add the column "Soru-EN" with value "Pending" for all rows

for i in df.index:
    x = df.loc[i,'Soru-TR'] # tip: using pandas.loc[] to access values is better.
    output = translate_client.translate(x, target_language=target)
    output2 = output['translatedText']
    df.loc[i, "Soru-EN"] = output2 # assign the translated text to its equivalent cell.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please mark it as best answer (click the check icon). Glad i helped, good luck buddy

Comment: When i click: (Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.) im sorry buddy

Comment: Oh it is fine haha

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add columns with same name so change every name in iteration.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((50, 75)))  


empty_column_index= [i for i in range(3, df.shape[1] + 1, 4)]
empty_colum_names = [f'EmptyColumn{i}' for i in empty_column_index]

for column, name in zip(empty_column_index, empty_colum_names ):
    df.insert(column+ 1, name, '')

print(df.head())
```